# Get Year & Month as string from Date with NA values

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Here is current df:

```
ID  Date
1   3/29/2017
2   
3   11/5/2015
4   
5   2/28/2017
```

I am trying to get year + month as a string in the new column. And this is my code:

```
df["Year"] = df["Date"].dt.year
df["Month"] = df["Date"].dt.month
df["yyyy_mm"] = df["Year"].map(str) + "-" + df["Month"].map(str)
```

The issue is when I extract the year and month from the date, it will return the float type.

```
ID  Date        Year        Month   yyyy_mm        I hope to get this
1   3/29/2017   2017.0      3.0     2017.0-3.0     2017-3
2                                   nan-nan         
3   11/5/2015   2015.0      11.0    2015.0-11.0    2015-11
4                                   nan-nan 
5   2/28/2017   2017.0      2.0     2017.0-2.0     2017-2
```

I tried to use `df["Date"].dt.year.astype(int)` to convert it to int, so that there is no `.0`, but I got this error: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer. Because there NAN in column.

I don't want to fillna for all the year and month with 0 or something else, i just want to keep them empty since `date` is empty at that row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should perform string conversion directly from `Date` using [`pd.Series.dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html).

This not only ensures `NaT` rows remain `NaT`, but strings are better formatted, e.g. zero-padding for months.

```
df["yyyy_mm"] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')

print(df)

   ID       Date    Year  Month  yyyy_mm
0   1 2017-03-29  2017.0    3.0  2017-03
1   2        NaT     NaN    NaN      NaT
2   3 2015-11-05  2015.0   11.0  2015-11
3   4        NaT     NaN    NaN      NaT
4   5 2017-02-28  2017.0    2.0  2017-02
```